Condition is not working - Send email SAS GUIDE
I have to do a condition in SAS Guide if the SYSERRORTEXT is blank or not, but the code that I created is giving me only the value 0, indicating that the code is not good, even I received the e-mail. I've tried everything for days, but anything is working. I've tried IS MISSING, IS NULL, " ", LIKE something etc. I've tried the variable SYSERR too, prxmatch('/ERROR\d+/', text) > 0, anything, but it's getting me crazy. How can I get the best code of it? Thank you very much!
%let emails = "eh@kl.com";

filename msg email
to=(&emails)
from="eflkjwh@kl.com"
subject="yurusg"
type="text/html"
attach=('C:\\Temp\\RESULT_VALID_DT_REF_BO.xlsx')
;

ods html file=msg rs=none;

proc odstext;
p " ";
p "Olá, ";
p " ";
p "Segue em anexo o resultado da validação da DT_REFERENCIA_BO nas entidades CONTRATO e CONTA. ";
p " ";
p "Obrigada. ";
run;
ods html close;

%END;

/\* Check if there was an error \*/
%put &SYSERRORTEXT ;

data Var_tab;
FORMAT varerror best8.;

proc sql ;

SELECT CASE WHEN "&SYSERRORTEXT" = "" THEN varerror = 1 ELSE varerror = 0 END AS VAR8
into :varerror
from WORK.Var_tab ;quit;



I want a variable telling me if the SYSERRORTEXT is blank or not.

"SAS Guide"?  Do you mean Enterprise Guide?  Your question seems to be about SAS code and does not appear to have anything to do with Enterprise Guide, which is just the tool you are using to submit the SAS code.

I think you would be better off using SYSCC instead of SYSERRORTEXT.
8         %let syscc=0;
49         %put NOTE: &=syscc &=syserrortext;
NOTE: SYSCC=0 SYSERRORTEXT=
50         
51         bad;
           ___
           180

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

52         %put NOTE: &=syscc &=syserrortext;
NOTE: SYSCC=3000 SYSERRORTEXT=180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
53         
54         %if &syscc GT 0 %then %do;
55            %let flag=1;
56            %end;
57         %else %do;
58            %let flag=0;
59            %end;
60         
61         %put NOTE: &=flag;
NOTE: FLAG=1


I really need to have the SYSERRORTEXT because i need to put this information at the control.

I have to adapt some stuffs but it really worked. Thank you very much!

I think you want:
proc sql ;
    SELECT CASE WHEN "%superq(SYSERRORTEXT)" = "" THEN  1 ELSE 0 END into :varerror
        from WORK.Var_tab ;
quit;

In your original code inside the CASE WHEN clause, varerror = 1 is a logical expression which equals 1 if varerror is 1 and equals 0 otherwise. varerror = 0 is a logical expression which equals 1 if varerror is 0 and equals 0 otherwise. Because varerror is missing, neither of the conditions is true so the result is 0.
The %superq() is included in case &SYSERRORTEXT contains double quotes.

It gave me the error above:
62         proc sql ;
63         
64         SELECT CASE WHEN "%superq(&SYSERRORTEXT)" = "" THEN  1 ELSE 0 END into :varerror
ERROR: Invalid symbolic variable name INVALID VARIABLE NAME ATTEMPT ASSIGN A VALUE TO A READ-ONLY SYMBOLIC VARIABLE (SYSERRORTEXT..
65         from WORK.Var_tab ;
65       !                    quit;


I used this suggestion at ChatGPT and gave me 0 instead of 1 too:
proc sql ;
SELECT CASE WHEN symget('SYSERRORTEXT') = "" THEN  1 ELSE 0 END into :varerror
from WORK.Var_tab ;quit;

%SUPERQ() takes as input the NAME of the macro variable, not its value.  Remove the &.

Thanks @Tom, the code is OK now, but I had the same wrong zero again =(

54         /* Check if there was an error */
55
56         %let &syserrortext=;
NOTE: A missing equal sign has been inserted after the variable name ATTEMPT.
57
58         %put &SYSERRORTEXT ;
Attempt to assign a value to a read-only symbolic variable (SYSERRORTEXT).
59
60         data Var_tab;
61         FORMAT varerror best8.;
62         run;

@shaun_m I did this code, but i'm getting the error above

There should be no & in the %let statement. %let syserrortext=;

@shaun_m I received the e-mail, the variable gave me zero and I had this error:
54         /* Check if there was an error */
55
56         %let syserrortext=;
ERROR: Attempt to assign a value to a read-only symbolic variable (SYSERRORTEXT).

Sorry @fercs89. My set-up is non-standard and I can write to the SYSERRORTEXT variable. The standard is that it is a read-only variable. I suggest you follow Data Null's advice and use SYSCC instead of SYSERRORTEXT for this check. If you have an error you can still use the value of SYSERRORTEXT when you need to use it.

Thank you for you patience @shaun_m . I'll test here and I'll get in touch =)

@shaun_m I adapted some stuffs in Data Null's code and it worked. Thank you for your help!

The SYSERRORTEXT macro variable is readonly.  The only way to change it is to generate an ERROR message.  See https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/syserrortext-macro-variable/td-p/188721#:~:text=Automatic%20macro%20variable%20SYSERRORTEXT%20is,the%20last%20ERROR%3A%20line%20logged.
Because of that you might what to use your own user created macro variable instead. Let's call it USERERRORTEXT just to have something to use in an example.  So when you detect there has been an error immediately save SYSERRORTEXT to USERERRORTEXT and then reset SYSERRORTEXT so that you can later check it.
So before your step that you want to capture the error message make sure it is cleared.
 %put NOTE: This ERROR message is used to clear the SYSERRORTEXT macro variable.;
 %put ERROR: %str( );

Then immediately after the step that might generate an error add code like:
%let usererrortext=%qsysfunc(trimn(%superq(syserrortext)));
%let varerror=0;
%if &usererrortext ne %then %do;
   %put NOTE: This ERROR message is used to clear the SYSERRORTEXT macro variable.;
   %put ERROR: %str( );
   %put varerror=1;
%end;

Then in your code test the value of VARERROR and store the value of USERERRORTEXT.

I used the SYSCC variable in the Data Null's code and it worked. Thank you for your help!
